# Posting Rails code in text areas

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way in Rails to escape code inserted in a textarea? If I post rails code at this point, there are some symbols that conflict with html (<< for instance) that don't render. Any thoughts on how to avoid this? In fact in some things I test, I make a post and it doesn't show up at all when I try to render it. I assume this is because of some conflict with the code I am posting.

Comment: How do you render it? Are you aware of the HTML `<code>` tag?

Comment: Can you give a example on how you render the textarea in erb/html now?

Comment: Are you trying to output code as the value to a `<textarea>`, or trying to render out the contents of a submitted `<textarea>`?

Comment: render the contents of a submitted text area

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly call a javascript function on window.onload/$(document).ready, that will remmove the html specific special character